# Stomp websocket gives ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected

Tags: netty, spring-websocket, activemq-artemis, sockjs

I have been working with stomp and sockjs for sometime. The following error occurred in the logs for stomp.

```
05:49:52.704 [71] [tcp-client-loop-nio-2] ERROR io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector - LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. See https://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html for more information.
Recent access records:
Created at:
        io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.newDirectBuffer(PooledByteBufAllocator.java:402)
        io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:187)
        io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:173)
        io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.buffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:107)
        org.springframework.messaging.tcp.reactor.ReactorNettyTcpConnection.send(ReactorNettyTcpConnection.java:60)
        org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler$RelayConnectionHandler.forward(StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler.java:896)
        org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler.java:579)
        org.springframework.messaging.simp.broker.AbstractBrokerMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractBrokerMessageHandler.java:281)
        org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel$SendTask.run(ExecutorSubscribableChannel.java:144)
        io.opentracing.contrib.concurrent.TracedRunnable.run(TracedRunnable.java:30)
        java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Netty.docs: Reference counted objects
```

I am using ActiveMQ Artemis as the broker. I am not quite able to figure out the reason for memory leak. Can anybody throw some light to possible reasons for this to happen?

Comment: @PeterCatalin Unfortunately no. It happened to stop after sometime. we couldn't observe it anymore. But if you find you can post it here.

Comment: @PeterCatalin We did analyse the JVM though, we saw that there was a memory leak regarding a bean of WebSocket. There was some `Upgrade` beans that wasn't being released which was created as part of WebSocket connection.

Comment: Thanks you for your insight, if I figure something out I'll let you know.